# « Nouveau » après le nom

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

Je connais deux cas où l'adjectif *nouveau* tombe après le nom qu'il décrit:

- *Ville nouvelle*: utilisé dans les pays du Maghreb pour désigner les quartiers construits sous l'occupation française (par opposition à la *médina* / *vieille ville* )
- *vie nouvelle*

Mais pourquoi? *nouveau* n'appartient pas à la liste d'adjectifs qui changent de sens selon leur position (comme *ancien*), et il existe quand même le mot cousin *neuf* si l'on avait besoin de nuance.

Comment: Beaujolais nouveau ? :-) Il doit probablement y avoir d'autres examples.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/nouveau) en a un certain nombre.

Comment: Aussi, _nouvelle_ ne tombe pas _nécessairement_ après le nom: _chaque jour, il partait à la découverte d'une *nouvelle ville*_. Et _dans sa nouvelle vie, il n'avait plus de temps pour la pêche_.

Answer (score 5):

C'est sûrement très subjectif, mais une *ville nouvelle* ne peut se concevoir qu'en opposition à une *vieille ville*, c'est à dire que l'on a créé récemment à côté de l'ancienne (et toujours vivante) cité, un lieu d'habitation et de vie.

La *nouvelle ville* ferait plutôt référence à une ville créée ex-nihilo comme Brasília.

On ne dira pas une *ville vieille* si l'on veut dire ancienne, mais pour une ville où tout est vieux, usé, délabré, abandonné... et de moins en moins habité.

J'ai une *nouvelle vie*, j'ai abandonné mon ancien mode de vie pour un nouveau, il y a eu un événement particulier qui à modifié le cours de ma vie.

Lorsque l'enfant paraît, une *vie nouvelle* arrive au monde.

Bien que l'on puisse inverser l'ordre des expressions dans chacun de ces exemples, je les ai très souvent entendues dans cet ordre pour signifier la continuité ou non de quelque chose d'ancien.

Comment: On dirait *vieille ville* pour parler du cœur historique, non?

Comment: @Hautfrançais Oui, cela confirme l'opposition avec la *ville nouvelle*, celle qui n'est PAS historique

Answer (score 0):

*Nouveau* ne tombe pas nécessairement après le nom, même en association avec *ville* et *vie* comme dans les exemples de l'OP:

> Chaque jour, il partait à la découverte d'une *nouvelle ville*.
>
> Et dans sa *nouvelle vie*, il n'avait plus de temps pour la pêche.

Sont tout à fait correctes. Dans la première phrase, on indique seulement qu'il visite une ville différente chaque jour. Dans la deuxième, on aurait du mal à utiliser l'ordre *vie nouvelle*.