# Une différence entre « nouveaux mots » et « mots nouveaux » ?

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

> Un nouveau procédé et un procédé nouveau.

Quelle est la différence ?

De ces deux variantes, laquelle est plus appropriée dans ce contexte et pourquoi ?

- *Ces mots nouveaux sont appelés néologismes*.
- *Ces nouveaux mots sont appelés néologismes.*

Comment: Une autre question en rapport avec celle-ci. https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13632/79. Mais cet exemple est à mon avis plus intéressant, car j'utiliserais « mots nouveaux » sans hésiter. Avec « nouveaux mots » on comprendrait « ceux dont il est question à présent ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Un nouveau procédé et un procédé nouveau

Très similaires. Peut-être une subtile différence d’emphase, la première insistant davantage sur le fait qu’il s’agit d’un procédé, la seconde sur le fait qu’il est nouveau. Dans une utilisation réelle, on pourrait à la rigueur en privilégier l’un par rapport à l’autre, selon le type de message que l’on transmet, mais les différences sont subtiles. Peut-être le *procédé nouveau* contraste-t-il davantage avec l’ancien que le *nouveau procédé* ???

- Nous fabriquons cet acier à partir d’un procédé nouveau.
    → *Peut-être une modification majeure de nos anciens procédés, ou un procédé développé à l’externe, et greffé sur notre circuit de production...*
- Nous fabriquons cet acier à partir d’un nouveau procédé.
    → *Peut-être une petite modification d’un appareil existant, le changement de quelques paramètres, l’adjonction d’une pièce ou d’un circuit parallèle, développé à l’interne...*

Mais ces subtilités échapperaient peut-être à l’interlocuteur, et le contexte plus large expliquerait sans doute de quelle manière comprendre le message, même si l’on en modifie l’ordre des mots.

---

> Ces mots nouveaux sont appelés néologismes.

On donne le nom *(néologisme)* servant à désigner les mots d’apparition récente *(les mots nouveaux)*. Il s’agit d’une généralité complètement indépendante des mots nouveaux considérés.

L’utilisation de « ***Ces*** » en début de phrase nous indique qu’il a été auparavant question de l’apparition de mots dans la langue, et l’on nous indique maintenant le terme qui les désigne en tant que mots d’apparition récente, et l’on comprend que tout autre mot d’apparition récente pourra à son tour recevoir cette dénomination.

---

> Ces nouveaux mots sont appelés néologismes.

La différence est subtile, mais pour moi, cette façon de s’exprimer est moins générale que la première. On pourrait l’interpréter comme incluant une contrainte non-spécifiée, c’est-à-dire que ***ces*** mots d’apparition récente sont appelés néologismes, mais qu’il pourrait exister certains autres mots d’apparition récente auxquels ne conviendrait pas l’appelation *néologisme*.

L’ordre d’énonciation *(ces mots nouveaux vs. ces nouveaux mots)* me semble introduire une différence, la première insistant davantage sur la **nouveauté** de ces mots, la seconde davantage sur le fait qu’il s’agit de **ces mots**, accessoirement nouveaux.

Answer (score 1):

Les 'mots nouveaux' sont intrinsèquement nouveaux, des néologismes. Des 'nouveaux mots' peuvent n'être nouveaux que dans le contexte : 'dans mes mots croisés je viens de trouver deux nouveaux mots', pas 'deux mots nouveaux'.