# Emploi de la locution "in fine"

Tags: usage, latin

> In fine, je souhaiterai adopter une approche multi-échelle en privilégiant la complémentarité des différentes informations.

Peut-on employer la locution *in fine* comme dans la phrase ci-dessus ? Est-ce une locution connue ? Peut-on l'utiliser dans un registre familier / moins soigné comme l'indique les exemples ici :

https://lachal.neamar.fr/In_fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une très pertinente remarque [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/34198/13100) concernant l’utilisation en français de l’expression *in fine*, différente de son avatar anglais.

Quant à la phrase proposée :

> In fine, je souhaiterai adopter une approche multi-échelle en privilégiant la complémentarité des différentes informations.

...la tournure à privilégier pourrait varier selon que l’on désire...

- résumer brièvement ce qui précéda :

  > **En conclusion / [En définitive](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9finitive)**, je souhaiterai adopter [...]
  >   **Bref / Enfin / En résumé**, je souhaiterai adopter [...]
- introduire le dernier élément d’une liste en explicitant que l’exposé touche à sa fin :

  > **Finalement / En dernier lieu**, je souhaiterai adopter [...]
- indiquer ce qui deviendra souhaitable lorsque les événements physiques de ce monde auront évolué au point de rejoindre ce qui a été énoncé auparavant (je ne peux pas trouver ici et maintenant de tournure simple, ce qui ouvre la porte à d’innombrables variantes possibles...) :

  > **Lorsque tout ceci sera accompli / Quand nous en serons rendus là / Vers la fin de ce processus**, je souhaiterai adopter [...]

Comment: Merci ; pourquoi *une très pertinente remarque* et pas *une remarque très pertinente* ?

Comment: @Dimitris Probablement pour mettre immédiatement l'emphase sur la pertinence plutôt que sur le fait qu'il s'agit d'une remarque. C'est une simple décision stylistique que j'ai prise sans y penser. Les deux eussent été acceptables.

Comment: Oui, comme tu explique ici :-)! https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30253/une-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-nouveaux-mots-et-mots-nouveaux

Answer (score 6):

It has become extremely rare to read or use "In fine"; we would rather use "Finalement":

> **Finalement**, je souhaiterai adopter une approche multi-échelle en privilégiant la complémentarité des différentes informations.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Cependant le Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+fine&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20fine%3B%2Cc0 me semble la contredire, non ?

Comment: Dimitris, Google ne trouve que 14 occurrences pour le XXIe siècle, et la plupart sont de faux positifs (texte en latin ou en anglais). Le seules utilisations avérées concernent le domaine bancaire (prêt avec remboursement in fine).

Comment: Peut-être pas si rare, après tout : *Pour l'expert ayant requis l'anonymat, Boeing va sans aucun doute être sanctionné en Bourse, mais il souligne **qu'in fine** les dégâts seront limités pour le groupe, en duopole avec l'européen Airbus.* Lu aujourd'hui dans [L'Obs](https://www.nouvelobs.com/monde/20190311.OBS1461/crash-en-ethiopie-la-securite-du-boeing-737-max-en-question.html)

Comment: @jlliagre Ça ressemble à l'influence de _enfin_ et on n'a pas employé les italiques, de sorte que ça pourrait être un calque de l'anglais, voire un anglicisme, vu que le sens _en résumé_ colle. Enfin on voulait peut-être dire _au final_ mais on trouvait ça [critiquable](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=au%20final&id=5429) et on a voulu soutenir le tout avec le latin en fioriture. Je trouve ça baroque.

Answer (score 3):

COMPLÉMENT DE RÉPONSE

La définition du TLFi donne la base de l'utilisation actuelle de « in fine », qu'il ne faut pas confondre avec l'anglais « in fine » (finally, in short, to sum up) ;

> (TLFi) IN FINE, loc. adv.
>   [**Utilisé *notamment* dans des apparats crit., des notes, des réf.**] À la fin, dans les dernières lignes, dans la partie finale (d'un livre, d'un chapitre, d'un paragraphe).
>
> - En tout cas, il y aura une longue note explicative *in fine*¹. Je causerai de tout cela demain avec l'aimable auteur d'Astarté.

Voir les exemples d'utilisation (1985-2008)  [ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%222%20in%20fine%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1985,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_fr&gws_rd=ssl)

¹ <sub>exceptionnellement en italique dans cet exemple du TLFi ; généralement dans les exemples le mot en entrée n'est pas en italique ; raison inconnue</sub>