# Why is it "une vie meilleure", not "une meilleure vie"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

In the following sentence:

> Nous pouvons espérer une vie meilleure.

It uses the order of *une vie meilleure*, not *une meilleure vie*.

However, *meilleur* is one of [the BAN**G**S adjectives](http://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/adj3.html) and thus I thought it should be put before the noun *vie*. That said, when I googled both *une meilleure vie* and *une vie meilleure*, both get enough results, and without a warning such as *Do you mean [insert the other expression]?*.

So why is the position of *meilleure* after the noun, and if both are correct, what is the difference in its meaning?

Comment: Voir ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30253/nouveaux-mots-vs-mots-nouveaux

Comment: Aussi cette question : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/nouveau-apr%C3%A8s-le-nom

Comment: Pour les locuteurs natifs du français qui ne connaissent pas l'acronyme BA(N)GS : En cours FLE (français langue étrangère) on apprend (niveau <B2) que : the placement of most adjectives in French is after the noun: un escargot parlant, une fourmi travailleuse, des tatous intelligents, etc. There is a small group of adjectives, however, that normally precede the noun. These adjectives may be categorized as adjectives of Beauty, Age, Numbers Goodness, and Size (BANGS).  http://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/adj3.html

Comment: C'est une règle mnémonique appartenant dans la même catégorie des règles souhaitant supporter apprentissage comme MRSDRVANDERTRAMPP pour les verbes conjugués avec être comme verbe auxiliaire.

Comment: 'Vie meilleure' is more emphatic, precisely because it is less natural: it stands out. It's literaly life-changing.

Comment: @LPH Fair enough, I made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While BANGS is a good rule of thumb, it's not a strong, 100% true rule.

Many adjectives that are usually before the noun can be placed after it in some cases, mostly for historic or stylistic reasons (it "sounds better" or "sounds more/less formal").

Here the meaning is the same.

Comment: @LPH What do you mean, "fast"?

Comment: [*fast*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fast) has two opposite meanings in English: the usual one, vite, and a rarer one, bien attaché ou bien coincé (I can't think of a single French word for it, and apparently, neither can Wiktionnaire); *hard and fast* is an idiom which uses the second meaning.

Comment: @PeterShor Maybe _Larousse en ligne_ provides some [insight](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/hard-and-fast/585452?q=fast+and+hard) i.e. _absolu(e)_ or _strict(e)_. Maybe _infaillible_ comes close in context? See also [_inflexible, rigoureuse_](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=HARD+FAST+RULE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs). Those are really along the lines of the terms LPH used in English (strict, inflexible). Imho _absolu(e)_ is the best.