# Is it “peluche rêveuse” or “rêveuse peluche”?

Tags: grammaire

Does bangs apply to the adjective? Not sure because the word I want refers to "dreamy", but I don't know if it applies to any of the BANGS categories.

Comment: bangs ? Beaucoup de sens possibles https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bang, de sigles différents https://www.acronymfinder.com/BANG.html

Comment: @Personne For BANGS see [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34509/358) or [this answer to another question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4606/358).

Comment: Intéressant, merci de vous intéresser à la francophonie, mon seul espace d’expression :-) — N.B. : Les prochaines fois, mettez un lien directement dans votre question lorsque vous utilisez un acronyme [*https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acronyme → § B - 1*] inconnu de ceux qui ne sont que francophones.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *rêveur*/*rêveuse* falls into any of the BANGS (Beauty, Age, Numbers, Goodness, and Size) categories of adjectives that would warrant its appearing before the noun.  *Peluche rêveuse* sounds much more likely than *rêveuse peluche*.

Answer (score 1):

Both seem correct, so this is not what you would call a "BANGS" case. In other words, the "rêveuse peluche" is more literary, although the other version is totaly correct.

Answer (score 1):

The main important thing is the context: poetry, since a **peluche** is *rêveuse*. So you can be literary as pointed out by KO the typo. But

> une rêveuse femme, un rêveur homme

are very unlikely out of this context.  And *un rêveur homme* will not be used, even in poetry. Maybe *un rêveur jeune homme*. Or perhaps *un rêveur, homme, ...* with very lonnnnng commas ;)