# How would you say "curious adventures" in French?

Tags: traduction

How would you say "curious adventures" in French?
I understand you can say curieuses aventures or aventures curieuses but don't understand the differences between them

Comment: Where to place the adjective will depend on the context and you are not giving much. You should really try to use the adjective in a sentence or say what you already know about *curieux*. Please visit the [help centre](https://french.stackexchange.com/help) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This question might help you: [*Les adjectifs qui ont deux sens*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/41058/358).

Comment: Indeed the adjective *curieux* can have two meanings (just as the adjective "curious" in Br. English), but using it with the noun *aventures* there's no hesitation as to the meaning (just as in English you would not say that adventures are inquisitive, but they can be strange). So where you will place the adjective will depend on other criteria than the meaning and if you want any serious help you'll need to modify your question and be more specific and use the words in a sentence, it's just possible that in the sentence you want to write it won't matter.

Comment: @None On peut voir deux sens pour _curieux_ dans _curieuses aventures_ et _aventures curieuses_, le deuxième par imitation de _aventures gourmandes_, _aventures qui flattent la gourmandise_, _aventures qui excitent la curiosité_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it "une vie meilleure", not "une meilleure vie"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34509/why-is-it-une-vie-meilleure-not-une-meilleure-vie)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to say "Les curieuses aventures", the difference is the context in which they are used.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE.  How does this answer the question? This would benefit from an explanation about the difference in  context and a source or citation.  Voici le [help] et le [tour] pour tes [edit]s.